# Are there are any attempts utilising sieve theory to attack the general $a p \pm 1$ problem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory, prime-gaps

It is currently an open question if there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2p + 1$ is prime (Sophie Germain primes) or that at least one of $24p \pm 1$ is prime.

Could Zhang's method, or the methods utilised by the associated Polymath8 project, give any absolute bounds $B$ along the lines of: "There are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $a p+k$ is prime for some $0<k<B$" or perhaps results along those lines for $k p+1$ for $0<k<B$?

Comment: The short answer is that neither Zhang nor Maynard’s methods can deal with primes of the form $ap + b$.

Comment: One can prove by the methods that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $ap+k$ is prime for $(a,k)$ in some finite list of pairs of *rational numbers* $a,k$.  But for $a$ an integer I think it is too hard.